# Delivering docker container to offline host

Tags: docker, windows-server-2012, cicd

I have a microservice project and GitHub repo hosting that project. The client's requirement is to deploy the project on Windows Server which is isolated from the internet (only private network). Another team will pull from my GitHub and deliver the contents via private network to Windows Server. Is there any possibility to run all the installations during the CI/CD process and deliver to server built docker container which is ready to use? (not just dockerfile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
docker save <image> > output.tar
```

and later, on the target machine:

```
docker load < output.tar
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

I encourage you to check out the official documentation linked above since the commands have support for both compression and cherry-picking specific tags etc.